# JModelica fails at compiling (make install)

Tags: jmodelica

I tried to install JModelica on my Ubunute 18.04 but I always get a make error.
(I've installed both the required pakages for python and python3)

I followed the installation guide from its userGuide.pdf (https://jmodelica.org/downloads/UsersGuide.pdf)  to the point i had to make install it.

```
$ sudo make install
```

I get the following error output (last few line):

```
Makefile:1127: recipe for target 'install-python-packages' failed
make[2]: *** [install-python-packages] Error 1
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/user/FMU/jmodelica/JModelica.org/build“ wird verlassen
Makefile:757: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/user/FMU/jmodelica/JModelica.org/build“ wird verlassen
Makefile:443: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

**EDIT:**
pretty much erverything is building but the target:

build-python-packages

```
$ sudo make install-python-packages
```

this throws the error from above. But I can't identify the wrong lines.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try
https://gitlab.com/christiankral/install_jmodelica/blob/master/install_jmodelica.sh

for more information see discussion:
[JModelica on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230042/jmodelica-on-ubuntu-18-04/55278253#55278253)